# Plone 5 convert site to intranet

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

I am using Plone 5, I have a site created that is public and I want to convert it to intranet, I have installed the Workflow addon but I can't seem to find a way to apply the intranet policy to the site I already created. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You don't need any "workflow addon". You probably installed the local worfklow policy support but it's not needed to switch a Plone default workflow policy

Comment: Could Dan's answer help you further? Feel free to reask, if anything's unclear.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able  to change the Workflow under "Content Settings" in the Plone Control Panel.

URL: **site.com/@@content-controlpanel**

then leave the top drop down menu set as "(default)" and update the "New workflow" drop down menu to the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

Plone ships with an "intranet_workflow", which you can choose and apply like described in Dan's answer.

However, this workflow might be too complex, depending on your usecase.

A very simple solution to create a basic intranet is, to set a folder's state to private and grant view-permissions via the sharing-tab of the folder to the group "Authenticated users" or a group of your choice.

You'll probably want to grant add-permissions, too, and if you want users be able to edit each other's articles, grant edit-permissions, as well.

The review-permissions should better not be granted, so articles will not accidentally be published, and you might want adjust your workflow to have "private" as the initial state of articles.

Comment: This is almost always how I implement a simple "intranet" section of a Plone site.